# What level are the curses a Hexcrafter Magus adds to their spell list?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, magus, archetype, curses

A [Hexcrafter Magus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus/archetypes/paizo---magus-archetypes/hexcrafter) adds spells with the Curse descriptor to their spell list:

> A hexcrafter magus adds the following spells to his magus spell list: *bestow curse*, *major curse*, and all other spells of 6th level or lower that have the curse descriptor.

What levels are they for him? For example, [Bestow Curse](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/bestow-curse) has two listed levels: several classes get it as a level 3 spell, but others get it as a level 4 spell. When the Magus adds those to his spell list, what level are they?

Answer (score 1):

### Undefined.

As far as I am aware the RAW and FAQ do not answer this question.  Wh[ile a forum post claims that an answer has been posted in the FAQ](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2pjdk?what-level-spells-are-the-Curse-spells-a), I cannot find it. Apparently, though;

> sometimes an older Answered in the FAQ note means, instead, No answer needed or The developers have declined to answer, the latter perhaps being the case here (user: HeyICanChan, [this thread on the paizo forums](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2mal1?UM-Spell-levels-for-a-Hexcrafters-curse-spells#1))

Ergo, to the best of my knowledge, it is undefined as to what spell level the magus would learn the curse spells as, and therefore it comes down to the GM.

I'd hazard that if the spell is available on a '6th level casting max' class, it should be added at that level, as the magus is a partial casting class also and that makes the most sense to me.  Individual opinions on that matter, though, will vary.

Comment: It was marked for a FAQ, it doesnt say it has been asnwered in a faq. That means they want an official clarification about the issue.

Comment: "5 people marked this as FAQ candidate. Answered in the FAQ. 1 person marked this as a favorite." 
I'm not familiar with the details of their forums, does that not mean it has an answer in the FAQ?

Comment: @lithas - You'd think so, but I couldn't find it in their FAQs.  If they mean some specific pathfinder forums faq or something, then I couldn't find that.  If anyone else can do so, then it certainly supercedes my answer.

Comment: @lithas  Here's a longer [thread](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2mal1?UM-Spell-levels-for-a-Hexcrafters-curse-spells#1) on the same topic with 19 folks marking it as a FAQ candidate and some bemoaning it's *Answered in the FAQ* yet it's not. However, sometimes an older *Answered in the FAQ* note means, instead, *No answer needed* or *The developers have declined to answer*, the latter perhaps being the case here.

Comment: Is it possible that when the hexcrafter magus Spells section says, "A hexcrafter magus adds the following spells to his magus spell list: *bestow curse*, *major curse*, and all other spells of 6th level or lower that have the curse descriptor," that the hexcrafter adds *all* iterations of the listed spell to his spell list? So, for example, a hexcrafter has the spell *bestow curse* on his spell list as *both* a 3rd-level spell *and* a 4th-level spell (with most folks only caring about the former, obviously)?

Comment: @HeyICanChan - That's enough of a stretch that I don't feel comfortable calling it RAW.  The rules mention 'learning blah as a blah level spell' enough times that it's dubious that they count as 'different spells'.  I think trying to rely on interpretations of raw that stretch that far leads you directly into crazy-land and it's better to just say that the rules don't say and the GM should rule on it.